# Run multiple commands in sqlite manager

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, sqlitemanager

It's possible to run more than one command in the direct SQL execution in SQlite Manager?
(useful if you insert a lot of data)

e.g.

```
insert into TestTable (Name, Age) values("Thomas", 25)
insert into TestTable (Name, Age) values("Peter", 29)
...
```

Thx

Comment: Did you try it? What was the result?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Solution is very simple ;-)

-> use a semicolon to separate the commands

```
insert into TestTable (Name, Age) values("Thomas", 25);
insert into TestTable (Name, Age) values("Peter", 29);
...
```

Comment: Thank you very very much.. ;) it totally solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you could write the statement as:

```
insert into TestTable (Name, Age) 
values
("Thomas", 25),
("Peter", 29)
;
```

**Edit:**  Please note, as per @DominiqueJacquel's comment, that this will only work in SQLite version 3.7.11+

Comment: That syntax will not work with all versions of SQLite, it was only added around 3.7.11 I think.

Comment: @DominiqueJacquel you are absolutely correct. This will only work in SQLite in version 3.7.11+

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you may work executemany() method instead of execute()

Something like:

```
values = [
    ("Thomas", 25),
    ("Peter", 29)
]
conn.executemany("insert into TestTable (Name, Age) values (?, ?)", values)
```

Will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file like:

```
$ cat query-list.sql
insert into TestTable (Name, Age) values("Thomas", 25)
insert into TestTable (Name, Age) values("Peter", 29)
...
```

Now run the command:

```
$ sqlite3 my-database.db < query-list.sql
```