# SQL: how to add a subquery to a query

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

I have the following query for my oracle database that consists of two seperate queries :

```
ResultSet rs2 = st2.executeQuery("select * from user_col_comments where  substr(table_name,1,3) !="+ "'TCT' and substr(table_name,1,4) != 'ARTZ' and (table in user_tables where secondary='N') ");
```

This compiles ok within my Java jdbc code. But when I run it, I get the following error:

```
 java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression
```

I'm aware that the second part of this query doesn't work:

```
(table in user_tables where secondary='N')
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work as I'm a complete newbie. And I don't know how to do it right. I checked this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35543805/how-to-combine-two-sql-database-query). But I don't think it gives me what I want. I would like to combine these two queries, so that I get all `user_col_comments` whose table is within `user_tables`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be a subquery, e.g.

```
and table in (select table_name from user_tables where secondary='N')
```

Comment: l needed to replace the "table" in your answer with "table_name". And that solved my problem :)thx